# Changing permissions of a Channel for a certain role discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a tempmute command that logs in to another channel, I have it so that when there is no channel called "modlog" it creates one but so far I have it so everyone cant type in it including me. How do I make it so a role called "Member" cant type in it only?

Code:

```
  `except:
  await ctx.send("No channel called 'modlog', creating one. (Note: Setup the permissions to allow 
  everyone to see the channel but cannot type in it")
  await asyncio.sleep(3)
  await ctx.send(":white_check_mark: Channel Created! :thumbsup:") 
  perms = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
  perms.send_messages=False
  await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name='modlog', permissions=perms)
  logs = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name="modlog")
  await logs.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
  guild = ctx.guild
  modlog = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name="modlog")
  await modlog.send(embed=kickEmbed)
  await modlog.send(embed=unmutelog)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)`
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing that

```
modlog = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name="modlog")
logs = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name="modlog")
await logs.set_permissions(modlog , send_messages=False)
```

So firstly you got the role and then update the channel perms. `ctx.guild.default_role` belong to `everyone`.
Lemme know if that doesn't work for you.